# How to move the short description above the add to cart button in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to move the short description above the add to cart button in Woocommerce[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNz21.png)

Can someone please help me accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You can move description like this. First remove the original hook for the description and after that you need to hook that to the desired order. For example.

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 35 );
} );
```

Note: This is just an example. This exact code may not work for you theme because it seems your theme has also customized the order of the product parts. Please modify the order accordingly to your theme.